# JS Accordion not pulling JSON data

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have an accordion that is created by using the JSON data but it doesn't seem to creating the accordion at all. I can see the div for the accordion but none of the elements are occupying it.

This is the head of HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js">
  .
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
```

This is the HTML body:

```
<body>
  <div class="rightcolumn">
    <h2>Questions</h2>
    <hr />
    <div class="accordion js-accordion">
      <div class="accordion__item js-accordion-item active">
        <div class="accordion-header js-accordion-header"></div>
        <div class="accordion-body js-accordion-body">
          <div class="accordion-body__contents"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

This is the JSON data:

```
{
  "rows": [
    {
      "title": "Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus",
      "content": "Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum. Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum."
    },
    {
      "title": "Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor",
      "content": "Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum. Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum."
    }
  ]
}
```

This is the js

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'data.json',
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'JSON',
  success: function(data) {
    $.each(data.blocks, function(index, element) {
      $('.accordion').append(`<div class="accordion__item js-accordion-item">
        <div class="accordion-header js-accordion-header">${element.title}</div> 
            <div class="accordion-body js-accordion-body">
                <div class="accordion-body__contents">${element.content}</div>
            </div>
        </div>`);
    });

    var accordion = (function() {
      var $accordion = $('.js-accordion');
      var $accordion_header = $accordion.find('.js-accordion-header');
      var $accordion_item = $('.js-accordion-item');

      // default settings
      var settings = {
        // animation speed
        speed: 400,

        // close all other accordion items if true
        oneOpen: false
      };

      return {
        // pass configurable object literal
        init: function($settings) {
          $accordion_header.on('click', function() {
            accordion.toggle($(this));
          });

          $.extend(settings, $settings);

          // ensure only one accordion is active if oneOpen is true
          if (settings.oneOpen && $('.js-accordion-item.active').length > 1) {
            $('.js-accordion-item.active:not(:first)').removeClass('active');
          }

          // reveal the active accordion bodies
          $('.js-accordion-item.active')
            .find('> .js-accordion-body')
            .show();
        },
        toggle: function($this) {
          if (
            settings.oneOpen &&
            $this[0] !=
              $this
                .closest('.js-accordion')
                .find('> .js-accordion-item.active > .js-accordion-header')[0]
          ) {
            $this
              .closest('.js-accordion')
              .find('> .js-accordion-item')
              .removeClass('active')
              .find('.js-accordion-body')
              .slideUp();
          }

          // show/hide the clicked accordion item
          $this.closest('.js-accordion-item').toggleClass('active');
          $this
            .next()
            .stop()
            .slideToggle(settings.speed);
        }
      };
    })();

    $(document).ready(function() {
      accordion.init({ speed: 300, oneOpen: true });
    });
  }
});
```

Can anyone help me out with where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Are you trying to create a jQuery plugin? Why is `$(document).ready(function() {})` inside an AJAX callback?

Comment: @TJ it is initialising at the bottom of that javascript file, it should just be an accordion that is filled with the json data that can be toggled open and closed

Comment: @TJ I followed a tutorial in all honesty and and so I'm not too sure

Comment: You seem to be iterating over `data.blocks` but the given data doesn't have a `blocks` property? Shouldn't it be `data.rows`?

Comment: @TJ That works, thank you!